# How to apply asynchronously fetched CSS into view

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm fetchinh a html bundled view asynchronously (html+css+js) using AngularJS inside an Ionic project with the following code:

```
.controller('Main', function($scope, $http, $sce, $window) {

$http.get('URL').
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.ui = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.create_ui);
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// called asynchronously if an error occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
});

});
```

The thing is that the provided CSS is using <kbd><link></kbd> tag and since the hml is injected, this links are never fetched and applied to style the view.

Is there any way to fetch or import these css and js scripts?

Thanks in advance, if more information is needed I'm willing to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="{{dynamicFile.href}}" type="{{dynamicFile.type}}"  />
```

You can set the `dynamicFile` in the callback.

```
.controller('Main', function($scope, $http, $sce, $window) {

$http.get('URL').
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.ui = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.create_ui);
    $scope.dynamicFile = data.dynamicFile;
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// called asynchronously if an error occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
});

});
```

Also this would be helpful https://github.com/Yappli/angular-css-injector

Comment: Thanks, the CSS injector module worked like a charm.